# server 2008r1 slow file transfer in one direction

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-transfer, broadcom

I have a problem of slow file transfer in one direction on a 3 of my servers with 2008 on them. the test i have done is to copy a 400Mb file from a PC to 1 server takes approx 30 secs if i then try to copy it back to the PC it estimates it as taking 9 hours for the transfer. I have 4 identical servers 3 have this problem the 4th has server2k3 and does not have this problem, i also have 2 other servers running server2008 that dont have a problem with the same test these both have intel CPU's while the problematic servers have AMD CPU's in them could this be a problem with AMD chips and server2008? 
If anyone has any ideas i would love to hear from you 
many thanks in advance
graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was that the broadcom driver needed to be updated for server 2008 all is now well and running fine

Answer (score 0):

Are they the same NICs? Or are you using onboard NICs?

It's possible that the driver for the NICs on the AMD boards isn't really taking data inbound as well. Could be that it just needs configuration and tuning. Maybe it's the switch, or something else in the configuration. When you copy to the AMD boxes, are you copying it TO the AMD box or getting on the AMD box and copying it from elsewhere to the (say desktop). How about the Intel CPUs? Need a little more information on the process and hardware.

Comment: i have set up the test because i am having some problems with server speed
the full process is from a pc if i copy the 400Mb file to the server c:/ it takes 30 seconds approx if i then try from the pc to copy the file back to the pc's C:/ it estimates the time as 9 hours and would take about that long even if i log onto the server and try to copy the file from the server to the pc it still estimates it as 9 hours
the hardware is all running at 1Gbps the servers are fujitsu and have on board broadcom NIC's the switches are all 3com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Broadcom BCM5709C and 2008 Server R1.  I tried driver updates and so on and finally discovered a network adapter setting to be the culprit.  If you pull up properties on the adapter in question, then click Configure... at the top, then click the Advanced tab - you can see a list of settings for the adapter's transport layer.  Set the IPv4 Large Send Offload setting to "disable".  I think this tells the adapter not to push packet acknowledgement to the switch - we're running an older switch that I'm betting can't cope with it (interestingly the BCM5708 cards seem to be ok with that setting enabled).